# How to get field types in MS CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new at programming altogether and need your help in finding a way out to the below query:
I need to find all the fields on a 'abc_contact' page with same field type (single line of text and  multiple lines of text) and then perform some logical operation. How can I get all the fields of same type through JavaScript?

Comment: You should provide some code of what you tried in order for us to help you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6881e99b-45e4-4552-8355-2eef296f2cd8#BKMK_getAttributeType

Answer (score 1):

As @Guido points out in his comment, you can access an attribute's type using:

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute(arg).getAttributeType()`

You can get all of the attributes from the entity attribute collection, loop through them and get their types:

`Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) {
  var attributeType = attribute.getAttributeType();
  // Perform logic based on attribute type
});`

Attributes collection reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_entityattributes

Answer (score 0):

```js
Type TYP = (entityObj.Attributes["columnName"]).GetType();
string TypeVal = TYP.FullName.ToString();
```